# Create a column that list all column names that contain negative values in that specific row

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have an extremely large dataframe.

Let's say I have something like:

```
> p
    fu2_difftime_mridate_d_date fu2_difftime_premri fu2_difftime_prevfu fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date
1                          30.4                12.7               -14.2                        6.4
2                          12.9               -48.1               -47.6                       13.3
```

I want to have an overlook of all the columns which contain 0 and negative values in each row. I seek a solution in `dplyr` that creates a new covariate which contain all column names that has 0 or negative values in each row:

```
> p
                negvalues fu2_difftime_premri fu2_difftime_prevfu fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date
1    "fu2_difftime_prevfu"               12.7               -14.2                        6.4
```

Data

```
p <- structure(list(fu2_date = structure(c(15428, 13746), class = "Date"), 
    fu2_mri_date = structure(c(16156, 13732), class = "Date"), 
    fu2_difftime_mridate_d_date = c(30.4, 12.9), fu2_difftime_premri = c(12.7, 
    -48.1), fu2_difftime_prevfu = c(-14.2, -47.6), fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date = c(6.4, 
    13.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If there are more than one columns being negative in some row (e.g. the 2nd row), how do you show it?

Comment: Preferably separated with commas: "name1", "name2", "name3", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse solution. Basically we test across all columns (note: across(,.. is the same as across(everything(), ...) if a value is negative with `. < 0` if true give back current column name with: `cur_column()`.
Thereafter we have to use `unite`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

p %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~case_when(. < 0 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(Neg_cols, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', ')
```

```
    fu2_date fu2_mri_date fu2_difftime_mridate_d_date fu2_difftime_premri fu2_difftime_prevfu
1 2012-03-29   2014-03-27                        30.4                12.7               -14.2
2 2007-08-21   2007-08-07                        12.9               -48.1               -47.6
  fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date                                Neg_cols
1                        6.4                      fu2_difftime_prevfu
2                       13.3 fu2_difftime_premri, fu2_difftime_prevfu
```

Comment: We have similar ideas but yours is quick a little. +1

Comment: But yours should also stay as an answer, it was shorter then mine, and interesting. So please add it!

Comment: But base R is the king here  :D

Comment: lol. you are right. but kings are also human beings. :-)

Comment: Who are controlled by the queens :P

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution can be,

```
apply(p[-c(1, 2)] <= 0, 1, \(i)toString(names(which(i))))
#                    1                                          2 
#"fu2_difftime_prevfu" "fu2_difftime_premri, fu2_difftime_prevfu" 

#Add to the dataframe

p$new <- apply(p[-c(1, 2)] <= 0, 1, \(i)toString(names(which(i))))

p
    fu2_date fu2_mri_date fu2_difftime_mridate_d_date fu2_difftime_premri fu2_difftime_prevfu fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date                                      new
1 2012-03-29   2014-03-27                        30.4                12.7               -14.2                        6.4                      fu2_difftime_prevfu
2 2007-08-21   2007-08-07                        12.9               -48.1               -47.6                       13.3 fu2_difftime_premri, fu2_difftime_prevfu
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

p %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ifelse(.x <= 0, cur_column(), NA)), .keep = "used") %>%
  unite("negative", sep = ", ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  bind_cols(p)

#                                   negative   fu2_date fu2_mri_date fu2_difftime_mridate_d_date fu2_difftime_premri fu2_difftime_prevfu fu2_difftime_fudate_d_date
# 1                      fu2_difftime_prevfu 2012-03-29   2014-03-27                        30.4                12.7               -14.2                        6.4
# 2 fu2_difftime_premri, fu2_difftime_prevfu 2007-08-21   2007-08-07                        12.9               -48.1               -47.6                       13.3
```